# Windows Firewall - simple way to block an IP address that is scanning? User keeps getting locked

Tags: security, user-accounts, windows-firewall

I am using Windows Server 2008 - fully patched.

One of my user accounts keeps getting locked.  It is easy enough to unlock it - but it is happening with increasing frequency - and the user is not entering incorrect passwords.

I checked the security log - and see attempts to scan from a specific IP address.  I would like to block all activity from this IP address.  Is this easy to do?  I don't have physical access to the server - so I am hesitant to experiment with setting up a rule that may accidentally block my access.

Also hoping that I can track down specific activity that is causing this user to get locked.  Isn't there an event that I can look for when the account gets locked?  I don't see it - and this scan that I mentioned above may not be related to the locking - as these 'failed logins' are not for the same user as the user that got locked.  We have been watching the logs as the lock happens - but no clues there yet.

Comment: Are there any automated applications that use this users credentials that are trying to authenticate using the previous password or expired credentials?

Comment: No - nothing that is running for that user.  I had thought that mapped network drives may be trying to reconnect - but none.

Comment: There is malware on the system, Windows firewall blocks All unsolicited incoming connections by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 (I'm hoping this is the same or similar for Server 2008) you can create custom rules in the 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security'.

In the Inbound rules section create a custom rule that applies to all programs, all ports, and then choose your IP address.

You can see [this site](http://programming4.us/desktop/3484.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I've done this and there is still traffic on that IP. :/